# How to access source code of a WEKA model file

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, modeling, prediction

I have been training WEKA model files and I want to see the contents of these.

I tried changing their file extensions to `.class` and `.java` but the results are not readable.

A Google search brought me to the question "[*content of a classifier 'model' file (weka-3-7-1)*](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/content-of-a-classifier-model-file-weka-3-7-1-td24641.html)" but there was no direct answer.

I want to see the actual code of the rules and weights of the model file, not only from visualization or seeing the generated buffer code.

Is this possible?

---

#### Additional

The reason why I want to see the source code of a `.model` file from WEKA is that:

### I need to prove that the model file I made is the actual one I generated from the dataset

I know that the result buffer provides the generated trees in decision tree classifiers but the other ones just show the weights and nodes.

Can you please give me alternative suggestions on how to deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible with Weka currently. When you save a model, you are actually serializing an object implemented by a specific algorithm. This class can contain arbitrary state variables used by learning algorithm. Consequently, it can be deserialized only back to instance of same class.

Theoretically it is possible for Weka to offer an interface that allows learning algorithms to output model as pure Java code instead of binary serialized instances but it is not there right now. I currently use proprietary ML framework at work that actually has these interfaces and many algorithms like decision trees and regression does output model as C++ code that you can directly add in your project eliminating run time dependencies.

More about Weka model serialization: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization

If you interested in just visualization see this: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Explorer+tree+visualization+plugins

Comment: Thank you, I was actually more interested in the Java code version of the models in order to give a proof that the model does exist to my peers.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the serialization path? I have used the models successfully using serialization but I don't think it's not enough proof for people unfamiliar with WEKA.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do following.

> I need to prove that the model file I made is the actual one I generated from the dataset

I suggest modify weka source code for your classifiers and do following.

1. Add a DataSourceHashKey field
2. Whenever you generate a classifier take a [cryptographic hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) of your data set (arff file) and set this value to DataSourceHashKey.
3. When you deserialize your model classes , this DataSourceHashKey will be available to you. Lets call it ModelDataSourceHashKey
4. Before you run your classifier, generate new DataSourceHashKey from your data source (arff file), lets call it CurrentDataSourceHashKey.
5. Due to properties of Hash function, your ModelDataSourceHashKey and CurrentDataSourceHashKey must be EQUAL. If they are not, then your new data source is different from this model's generated data source, even if this difference is only a space.

I would like to add also following points. Previous answer is mostly correct but it misses some points.

Some of the classifiers of weka can produce java code see [Generating source code from WEKA classes](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+source+code+from+WEKA+classes). Following excerpt taken from that link.

```
Some of the schemes in Weka can generate Java source code that represents their current internal state. At the moment these are classifiers (book and developer version) and filters (snapshot or >3.5.6).
```

Translation if classifier or filter implements [Sourcable (Source able?)](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Sourcable.html) interface, you can get java code version of your classifier/filter, see below.

```
weka.classifiers 
Interface Sourcable

All Known Implementing Classes:
AdaBoostM1, DecisionStump, J48, LogitBoost, OneR, REPTree, ZeroR
```

For all other classifiers , model files are [java serialized files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html). Note that, serialization is a **java concept** not a weka one, therefore all limitations belong to java. What you ask can be performed according to following [link](https://www.andlabs.org/presentations/Attacking_JAVA_Serialized_Communication-slides.pdf).

```
The serialized form contains sufficient information  
such that it can be restored to an identical clone of  the original JAVA object
```

But I think implementing Sourcable interface for your classifiers will be more easy than following that path.